# Weird characters XML

Tags: xml

Hi I'm facing a problem with an XML file. It feels like it's encrypted or something like that but I cant extract any information from it, it's unreadable. Anyone knows why ?

I've already tried to change encoding, it's the first time I see an xml file looking like this.

```
7zºØ'   òπ ñ¥‘      $       ä+E%Ïµ*–Å]   DòR  C,¿pµØícÅ±;Êˇ #}˘_ ÌËóoŸw ˝_ Ä≥´cÒÕ '8,°wJèé®Ì,   qæõ  Ú∏ óÎV #¸VÜu˚ "X   ∑UXΩ˘¿ˆ¿ûdµ˙˘”1-— tOÂ r Á"g ` ˙ó_˘˘ïÙ”yRÂ È|7v,Z‚±G3ÃÃîƒ·Æá´ïπ!÷5 ∞ıin ¬⁄ÉHã’ƒV "ˆ8Gl ó≤)q‘jªƒh„; sR£* «~™îu=Õ— iÄ ∂◊Ö‚ ,úRv¥ G# s ˙Éjt '/•:^Ên≥ ¥¸ à~0¡¶rå“ã¥<øQäR‘ £Ú h¬óz ØØäó ∏É£ 42X˚ˇ®?Ÿ Ën·åˆÚ˙ê÷πIÛ°¡
V E?
```

Comment: Why do you call it an XML file when it clearly isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two characters suggest it is compressed 7z data.

Comment: Perfect ! You solved my problem. Don't know how you recognized it but it was indeed a 7z file. So I simply changed the extension and extract data from it. Magic, I found several XML files well writed. 
Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Compressed data often looks like garbage and the first two characters were 7z!